# Rails Date Format in edit view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating Edit form in rails using partial for new and edit
I'm using date picker jquery so user can choose date with jquery-ui

my problem is how do I format all my date fields
because in edit form it's all showing 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
I would like it's showing 'dd-mm-yyyy'

for example booking-date, it's showing 2014-04-20, I would like 20-04-2014

I did change
 config/initializers/date_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d-%m-%Y"
it's working only in show form but not in Edit mode

also in rails console (using debugger) I check the date format is
'YYYY-MM-DD' , is there a way to change it

for reference below is my show.html.erb and edit.html.erb (partial)

show.html.erb

```
  <% if logged_in? %>
    <p>Booking Date <br> <%= @booking.booking_date %>  </p>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @booking %>
    <%= f.label :booking_date, "Booking Date" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :booking_date, :class => :datepicker, size: 10  %>
```

Comment: Hi, if the 'show' is working when you put @booking.booking_date soundls like the Rails it's working fine, however you mention that 'edit' still diplays the date in the wrong format, this perhaps might be related to jQuery, if thats the case this may help: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: thank you, I did remove the datepicker class and refresh the page but I still get same result

Comment: removing the class wont solve the issue, instead try to add the format to the date picker in your javascript code, something like this: datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy" })

Comment: thank you, yes I did this before, if I click on field it after I choose the date from jquery-ui it will showing dd-mm-yyyy but before I click the field it showing yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366567/customizing-datetime-format-in-en-yml-in-rails-3) can be of some help for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add date value manually if the form is edit.

```
=@booking.booking_date.striftime("%d-%m-%YYYY")
```

20-04-2014

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @booking %>
    <%= f.label :booking_date, "Booking Date" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :booking_date, :class => :datepicker, size: 10, :value=>"#{f.object.booking_date.striftime("%d-%m-%YYYY") unless f.object.new_record?}"  %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using your solution with little bit correction :value=>"#{f.object.booking_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") unless f.object.new_record?}"