# JQuery UI Datepicker shows wrong date when Editing model on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

When i'm creating my model **@bill** i have an attribute called **purchase_date**.
I select the date from datepicker and it works fine, my date in view format is dd-mm-yyyy.
But when i call action edit, it brings wrong date format yyyy-mm-dd and my field has a mask besides the datepicker, so it comes like 20/15/1116 and causes error on update.
I already tried force a ...

```
@bill.purchase_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

and parse :value in my field. If i put it in another page element goes right, but in my field don't.

Here is my code.

form.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :purchase_date, as: :string, :label => false, :required => true, :input_html => { :id => 'datepicker1', :style => 'width: 100px;' } %>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "http://s8.postimg.org/kryvquupd/calendar.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  $("#datepicker1").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"dd/mm/aaaa"});
});
```

Comment: I had similiar problem. I found a this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247371/rails-date-format-in-edit-view/)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the date format to `datepicker`

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "http://s8.postimg.org/kryvquupd/calendar.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
      dateFormat: dd-mm-yyyy   
  });
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for comment, i've already tried that, didn't work, it brings same 20/15/1115